# Can I ask about metodology employed by organizations that make reports of economic interest?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I'm planning to ask a question about the accounting methodology employed by the IMF on their GFS, the GFSM. Is this within the scope?

The would-be question:

> How can I identify whenever a GFS dataset is using accrued and cash values?
>
> I'm using the Government Finance Statistics from the IMF for a
>   project. I know that I can't operate with cash basis and
>   accrued values as the results can be skewed. I've found *[several
>   resources link follows]* that strongly imply that they prefer accrued,
>   but accept cash values. How can I identify whenever the datasets I'm
>   consulting use any of these?
>
> For example, [this query](http://data.imf.org/?sk=E86E9088-3830-4CA3-B240-1B0EC5E15221) and [it's metadata](http://data.imf.org/regular.aspx?key=60950584) makes no mention
>   of either.

- GFS: Government Finance Statistics
- GFSM: Government Finance Statistics Manual

Comment: My impression is that this would be a great question for this site. On another note, could you expand the acronyms? I don't know what GFSG means.

Comment: @jmbejara it means a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is on topic because it is a clear question regarding a query of economic related data. See the related [help page for this site](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Queries for Data: Queries for Data sets and data in general are on-topic here. You can also try the Open Data SE site.

Comment: Ι second on-topicness - it is very important that one understands the data collection / transformation methodology in order to use it correctly and not misleadingly.